# Nginx rendering 502 error page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, capistrano, puma

I'm trying to configure nginx with puma to server my Ruby on Rails application. Whenever I visit my page I get a 502 bad gateway error.

#### /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/puma-api

```
upstream puma_puma-api_production { 
  server unix:/home/deploy/apps/puma-api/shared/tmp/sockets/puma-api-puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
  listen  80 default;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
  error_page 500 502 504 /500.html;
  error_page 503 @503;
  root /home/deploy/apps/puma-api/current/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma_puma-api_production;
  location @puma_puma-api_production {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://puma_puma-api_production;
    # limit_req zone=one;
    access_log /home/deploy/apps/puma-api/shared/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /home/deploy/apps/puma-api/shared/log/nginx.error.log;
  }
  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
  location = /50x.html {
    root html;
  }
  location = /404.html {
    root html;
  }
  location @503 {
    error_page 405 = /system/maintenance.html;
    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
    }
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
  }
  if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$ ){
    return 405;
  }
  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
    return 503;
  }
  location ~ \.(php|html)$ {
    return 405;
  }
}
```

#### /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;


  access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;

  keepalive_requests 100;
  keepalive_timeout  65;


  gzip  on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_vary off;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml text/javascript application/javascript application/json text/mathml;
  gzip_min_length  1000;
  gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\.";


  variables_hash_max_size 1024;
  variables_hash_bucket_size 64;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  types_hash_bucket_size 64;



  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

#### app/config/puma.rb

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup DefaultRackup
port ENV['PORT'] || 5000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

#### deploy.rb

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'puma-api'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:chaione/puma-api.git'
set :user, 'deploy'

# set :nginx_domains, 'localhost'
# set :app_server_socket, "#{shared_path}/sockets/puma-#{fetch :application}.sock"

# Default branch is :master
ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
# set :deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app_name'

set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty, true
set :use_sudo, false
set :stage, :production
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Make sure local git is in sync with remote.'
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts 'WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master'
        puts 'Run `git push` to sync changes.'
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  # before :starting,     :check_revision
  after :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after :finishing,    :cleanup
  after :finishing,    :restart
end


# # Default value for :linked_files is []
# set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'public/images')
# set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

namespace :deploy do
  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end
end
```

#### app recipe

```
# create www directory
directory '/var/www' do
  user node['user']['name']
  group node['group']
  mode 0755
end

# create shared directory structure for app
path = "/var/www/#{node['app']}/shared/config"
execute "mkdir -p #{path}" do
  user node['user']['name']
  group node['group']
  creates path
end

# create database.yml file
template "#{path}/database.yml" do
  source 'database.yml.erb'
  mode 0640
  owner node['user']['name']
  group node['group']
end
```

Comment: Nginx has really great (and really noisy) debugging possibilities, which can be used for investigating problems within nginx, for example rewrite_log.

Comment: Nginx usually return HTTP 502 error when it can't communicate with your backend proxy, in your case
`server unix:/home/deploy/apps/puma-api/shared/tmp/sockets/puma-api-puma.sock fail_timeout=0;`

The exact error will be written in the error log file, in your case `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Make sure nginx process' user has permission to read from the socket and of course, the socket is up & running.

Comment: @MathewB. It does appear to be a permission issue. After adding the nginx user to a privileged group I'm still getting the same error `failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: ,`

Comment: If I change upstream to `server localhost:500` and start forman I'm able to get it working. But I'm having problems getting foreman to start in capistrano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have nginx communicating with your puma server via socket

```
/home/deploy/apps/puma-api/shared/tmp/sockets/puma-api-puma.sock
```

You have puma creating this socket at

```
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
```

I can't see `shared_path` defined anywhere in your code though. Make sure that these two match (or just hardcode the path to eliminate variables for now).

I would also first check if `/home/deploy/apps/puma-api/shared/tmp/sockets/puma-api-puma.sock` even exists.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. In my app recipe the shared path is defined as `/var/www/puma-api/shared/`. Is this a value I need to declare in deploy.rb? If so how?

Comment: If that's your value, then it's probably why nothing is working. Puma is creating the socket at `/var/www/puma-api/shared/tmp/sockets/??.sock`, and nginx is trying to read it from `/home/deploy/apps/puma-api/shared/tmp/sockets/puma-api-puma.sock`

Comment: I was able to get it work by replacing `/home/deploy/apps/puma-api/shared/tmp/sockets/puma-api-puma.sock` with `localhost:5000` and stating puma with foreman.